# Class name not definied, but it is

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just wanna create a `class` definition with a static field with a name. A file called `exercises.py` contains:

First error:

```
FAIL: test_00_packages (__main__.Ex00)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex00.py", line 55, in test_00_packages
self.assertTrue("Exercise00" in globals()) 
AssertionError: False is not true
```

Later:

```
class Exercise00:
    def __init__(self, STUDENT_NAME):
        self.STUDENT_NAME = 'Name Name'
```

But if I try to print `Exercise00.STUDENT_NAME` I just get
`NameError: name 'Exercise00' is not defined`

But I guess I defined it?!

Here the complete error:

```
ERROR: test_01_static_field (__main__.Ex00)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex00.py", line 60, in test_01_static_field
    print("[I] Name: " + Exercise00.STUDENT_NAME)
NameError: name 'Exercise00' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My task is to create a `class` called `Exercise00` with a static field `STUDENT_NAME`.

The line in ex00.py is:

```
def test_00_packages(self):
    self.assertTrue("Exercise00" in globals())
```

Comment: Please create an [mcve]

Comment: We need to see the code where you try to do the print, as well as the full traceback (people commonly misremember/misreport errors), and also explain whether this is in the same file or not.

Comment: It's an external file, which tries to print STUDENT_NAME

Comment: Well for one, `STUDENT_NAME` is an instance field so you'd need an instance of the object. but you still need to create a [mcve]

Comment: It doesn’t solve the first error you’re running into, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible-in-python for how to create a static field (class attribute) instead of an instance attribute like you have now.

Comment: We need to see more of what is in `ex00.py`. I think we need to see what is imported in the first few lines of the file.

Comment: the file is imported by from folder.exercises import Exercise00

Comment: Well, I don't understand how this `import` can work without error, and yet `self.assertTrue("Exercise00" in globals())` fails.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. The test class is in a separate file `exercises.py`; you need to import the relevant functionality from that file (`from exercises import Exercise00`) before the module contents are visible from `ex00.py`.
2. Once you fix that, you will get a different error. Like the name of the test says, you are supposed to be looking for a `static field`, i.e. something that belongs to the *class itself*. This code attaches `STUDENT_NAME` to *instances of* `Exercise00`.

Comment: Yes, I took that into account. In ex00.py, you need to have the import statement. Otherwise, ex00.py cannot use contents from exercise.py.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need to define `STUDENT_NAME` as a class-level field, not as an instance level attribute:

```py
    class Exercise00:
        STUDENT_NAME = 'Name Name'
```

You can notice in the error message that the test calls class level field `Exercise00.STUDENT_NAME`:

```py
print("[I] Name: " + Exercise00.STUDENT_NAME)
```

And you also need to import `class Exercise00` in the test module:

```py
from exercises import Exercise00
```

As soon as you add the import statement to the file with the test `ex00.py`, the class name string appears in `globals()` and the test passes.

Comment: could you please share another error details and the test?

Comment: There is an assertion Error about exercises.py.

Comment: Assert that class Exercises00 is in global

Comment: could you share the code and the exact error message in the question? It would be much more helpful